# bootstrap Angular app in specific element

Tags: angular

How can I bootstrap Angular (2+) app in a specific element and not in `body`?

I'm trying to create a small shell app that loads other apps in it and Angular2 is one of the application types I want to make sure are working.

Comment: The bootstrap element of a typical angular app is not the body. It's the root component of your app. Typically `<someprefix-app></someprefix-app>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put your root element, typically `AppComponent`with a selector of `app-root` wherever you want the app to bootstrap.

So it could be

```
<div class="some-sidebar">
  <app-root></app-root>
</div>
```

as a simple example.